# How to set a rotation transform that doesn't distort on device rotation?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

I am developing an iPad application that has a set of UIButton instances where I do a slight CGAffineTransform rotation in `viewWillAppear:` so that they are not perfectly aligned on the screen.  A problem occurs, though, when the device is rotated in any direction and the background image of the button becomes more and more skewed the more it is rotated:

Correct:

[image]

After a few device rotations:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using to animate the view on `viewDidAppear:`:

```
/*
 *  Animate video button
 */

CGPoint videoCenter = self.videoButton.center;

self.videoButton.center = CGPointMake(self.videoButton.center.x + 25.0f, self.videoButton.center.y + 25.0f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.videoButton.center = videoCenter;
                     self.videoButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, [self convertDegreesToRadians:4.0f]);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Do Nothing
                 }];
```

I have tried resetting the transform to what I need it to be in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, and though it lessens the degree to which it happens, after a number of rotations it produces a similar result.

I have tried changing `autoresizesSubviews` of the main view to be `NO`:

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

But then I have to layout my landscape orientation completely by hand, which I want to avoid.

**How do I set the rotation transform so that it does not distort the background images of my `UIButton` on device orientation?**

**UPDATE:**

I added some log statements in `viewWillRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and noticed that the button's width is growing.  This explains the image distortion, but why is it even changing?  That seems odd to me:

```
width       height
-------------------------------
268.574524  149.81514
286.267822  150
304.092621  150
321.91745   150
339.742279  150
357.567078  150
374.401642  150
391.236206  150
409.061066  150
425.895599  150
442.730164  150
459.564728  150
476.399292  150
493.233826  150
509.078125  150
524.922424  150
540.766663  150
556.611023  150
```

Comment: How did you set the autoresizing mask of the button?

Comment: @omz I have it only set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` because I need it to anchor to the bottom when the view is rotated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you aren't using images of the iPhone in your app, are you? Apple will reject the app for that.

Comment: @jrhurton I knew someone would bring this up, but this is for an Enterprise app where Apple's veto power does not reach. I appreciate it, though. :)

Comment: Are you doing any transforms other than rotation? Can you show us all the code related to these transforms? This usually happens when you mix rotation and scale transforms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are experiencing may be due to autoresizing done by UIViewController upon interface rotation.  My suggestion is that you keep track of the *original* frame of the image view, and restore that original frame in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.  So, in `-viewDidLoad`, do something like this to save the frame of the view:

```
videoFrame = self.videoButton.frame;
```

In the header for this view controller, you should also declare `CGRect videoFrame` in order for the code above to work. Now, we can use this saved frame when the interface orientation is finished changing:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    CGPoint oldCenter = [self.videoButton center];
    [self.videoButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
    [self.videoButton setFrame:videoFrame];
    // restore previous center and rotation
    [self.videoButton setCenter:oldCenter];
    [self.videoButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, [self convertDegreesToRadians:4.0f])];
}
```